# Custom method for laravel router

Tags: laravel

I have access control list service (ACL) which contains list of permissions (enums) and roles stored in DB for each company. So I have companies and each company has many roles, each role has many permissions. In company flow I have a lot of resources (branches, services, masters, users, stats, etc) and each endpoint in the router should be integrated with ACL middleware.

For example to create a user I have this endpoint:

```
Route::post('/', [UserController::class, 'create'])->middleware('acl:'.PermissionEnum::USER_CREATE->value)->name('create');
```

And this is for creating a master:

```
Route::post('/', [MasterCreationController::class, 'create'])->middleware('acl:'.PermissionEnum::MASTER_CREATE->value)->name('create');
```

Now what I want to do is to have acl() method in the router, so I don't write

```
->middleware('acl:'.PermissionEnum::USER_CREATE->value)
```

But write:

```
->acl(PermissionEnum::USER_CREATE)
```

And do the rest there.

So how to override the router facade or service or whatever it is, so I could add my custom method, which will add a middleware to current state and return the Router instance, so I can continue with it? The ideal endpoint router I want to get is something like this:

```
Route::post('/', [MasterCreationController::class, 'create'])->acl(PermissionEnum::MASTER_CREATE)->name('create');
```

I want to make it this way, because I'll have about 300 endpoints and each endpoint has it's own permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Route` is macroable you should be able to extend its functionality as follows:

```php
use namespace Illuminate\Routing\Route;
...
Route::macro('acl', function ($input) {
    return static::middleware('acl:' . $input->value);
});
```

This should be added to the boot method in AuthServiceProvider or other providers you see fit.

More information can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#extending-collections).

Comment: That's briliant. Could you please also hint me, how could I tell IDE about that method? Cause it shows method not found error when holding the mouse on the method.

Comment: I haven't tried this method but if you're using VSCode, this package should help enhance auto-completion for macros and mixins https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper